# How can I add more keyboard layouts?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is it possible in Ubuntu 17.04 to add more keyboard layouts to the ones already listed? I use an English/Arabic keyboard and I could not locate the Arabic layout found on the keyboard of the PC I bought in any of the listed keyboards. So, I will have a problem with some of the keyboard buttons, since the layout of my PC is different! Can anyone help?

The name of the keyboard I need to include is: Arabic 102

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the command `setxkbmap -query` output?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question?  Is this some command I should put somewhere and tell you the result?  If so, pls explain in details I'm still 3 days old with Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes. One way is to open a terminal window with <Ctrl>+<Alt>+T, type that command followed by <Enter>, and let us know here what the result was.

Comment: This is what I got

rules:      evdev

model:      pc105

layout:     gb,us

variant:    ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run this command:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap ara,gb,us pc102
```

It will change the keyboard model to *pc102* (currently you have *pc105*) and make the basic Arabic keyboard layout available together with English (UK) and English (US).

It's easiest to reboot to make the new settings effective everywhere.

*Edit:*

If I understand it correctly, the pictures show - as an example - that typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> does not result in the '~' character, but to get it you need to type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+[the key to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key] instead. That behavior would indicate that your effective keyboard layout is *English (US)*, while the layout which seems to better match your keyboard is *English (UK)*. So try to switch to the *English (UK)* keyboard layout.

Comment: I did.  Nothing happened and all still the same!

Comment: The thing is that this keyboard is not even found in the list of keyboards!

Comment: @NermeenHussein: Not all keyboards are. If my suggestion didn't make a difference, you need to be much more specific in your question. Maybe show a picture of the keyboard, explain exactly which keys don't behave as expected, etc.

Comment: Ok, I took pictures, can u pls tell me how to paste them here?

Comment: I think I found a way to add the pictures.  I edited my original question and added 2 pictures for your perusal.  In the first one, I indicated for you a letter on the keyboard, but this button does not write this letter; another one does (which I indicated for you in the second picture).  Is it clear now?

Comment: @NermeenHussein: I think so. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Wow!! That solved the problem.  You're a genius :-))  Really, the best solutions are always the simplest.